# Android java : null context in a class that extend Application

Tags: java, android, android-context

I have a class extending Application. When I try to get the context of that class either by using "getApplicationContext" or by using "getBaseContext", the context is allways null.

I need the context to use "getSharedPreferences".

The error printed is :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)

What am I doing Wrong or what are some other ways I can use "getSharedPreferences" without the context (if possible) ?

Thanks for the help.

**edit with some code :**

I'm initializing the class "DeviceInfo" in my main class. the class "DeviceInfo" extends Application. In it's constructor I tried to do :

```
protected DeviceInfo() {

        context = getApplicationContext();
}
```

wich gives me the same error as mentioned earlier.

and here is the main line that is causing me trouble...

```
SharedPreferences key = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("keys", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**final edit** : thanks all, I took all your inputs and realized I wasn't doing it the right way at all. I changed all my code and now it works, thanks again.

Comment: Share your code plz!

Comment: Are you calling the method outside of or before onCreate()?

Comment: from where you are calling method getApplicationContext() ?

Comment: I edited my question, i tried to use "this" instead, same error..
Also i cant call it inside OnCreate since my class extends Application and not Activity, but I might be wrong

Comment: there is no constructor needed for a class that extends Application (since youre never going to insantiate this class manually)... but it still has onCreate, so just do it there...

Comment: 'this' isn't going to help anything.  'this' is implied.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your Application's `Context` hasn't been created before you're trying to access it.  To ensure that your `Context` has been created, you should wait to access your `Context` until `onCreate()` before attempting to access your context object.

For example:

```
public class DeviceInfo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SharedPreferences key = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("keys", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

}
```

You can also use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())` to access a default preferences file.

Comment: The onCreate function is never called and i don't understand why

Comment: Have your defined your application's name in the Android manifest?  <application
  android:name=". DeviceInfo" ...

Comment: I cant because I already have a class that extends Application

Comment: You said '"DeviceInfo" extends Application' in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a class which extends `Application`, you must define the `android:name=".YourClass"` property inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file inside the `application` tag.

Comment: Anyhow, you are having two classes now which extends from Application?